# Something simmilar to Visual Studio T4 in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, t4

I am looking for something that could read external data (e.g. XML) and then generate source code file. Main reason is to have single definition file and then make Visual Studio to generate C# code and IntelliJ to generate java code.

---

Visual Studio T4 is template engine intended to produce source code.

Answer (score 1):

The TextTransform.exe that runs T4 is a separate .net executable (even though it links to some of the Visual Studio dlls), so if you have both development environments in the same box, you can run the Java generation (even if it needs to be as a separate process spawning task).

Comment: yeh, I thought about this. Thanks if there will be nothing "native" I will investigate this more tightly.

Comment: @MikeChaliy have you found anything native in the mean time (it's just about 8 years) ;-)